# Pronunciation of Korea and Career

Tags: pronunciation, rhoticity

Are the pronunciations of `Korea` and `Career` identical?

Comment: Only if you're a 'non-rhotic' speaker.  In standard North American English, in Scotland, Ireland and a fair chunk of England, the 'r' at the end of 'career' is pronounced.

Comment: Not even then: the first vowel may well be different (it is for me).

Comment: The second syllable can differ as well: *career* rhyming with *here* and the second syllable of *Korea*  splitting into 2 and rhyming with *Sofia*.

Comment: @DavidGarner To be fair, there are non-rhotic native speakers in North America as well, although they are in the minority.  Think *Hahvuhd* or *Southehn*.

Comment: These words are quite different to most native American and British speakers, though maybe not to a speaker of Australian English. The vowel durations are different: the second syllable of *career* is considerably longer than the  final two syllables of *Korea* combined, though maybe not for Aussies, who tend to clip their vowels.

Comment: @TimRomano If I remember correctly, you spent some time in Somerset? For speakers in Somerset there'll probably be an /r/ at the end of *career*, but for RP speakers, these two words will mostly be homophones.

Comment: @tchrist That's why I wrote 'standard Northern American English'.  Maybe there's a better term, but I think you know what I meant.

Comment: @Araucaria. Good memory :)  To my ear, although they are close, even in RP there is a difference between *Korea* and *career* that hinges on the quality of the final syllable: 'career' ends with an up-glide or a constant-pitch off-glide and 'Korea' ends with a drop.

Comment: https://translate.google.co.uk/#auto/en/I've%20spent%20my%20career%20in%20Korea.   FWIW. Google Lady is somewhat unpredictable.

Comment: @DavidGarner No, you’re of course correct. I just wanted to make sure other people (not you of course, and non-native speakers especially) who aren’t from North America don’t get the idea that absolutely everyone is rhotic here by birth. That said, both “general/standard” American and Canadian are indeed rhotic, so the non-rhotic varieties are sometimes stigmatized or parodied by speakers of other dialects. For example, “Hahvuhd” speakers might be ridiculed for sounding posh and “Southehn” speakers for sounding hick. Both positions are untenable, but still occur.

Comment: Thanks, @tchrist.  For future reference, IS there an accepted term?  Your use of 'general' rings a bell.

Comment: I've just seen 'General American' in @Araucaria's answer.

Comment: @DavidGarner Another term often used (which sounds a bit less stigmatising) is _Broadcast American_; but the most common term is still [General American](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_American).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a speaker of Southern Standard British English (RP), these two words are homophones for me. They are both pronounced /kə'rɪə/.

However, SSBE is non-rhotic - we only pronounce /r/ before a vowel sound. For speakers of rhotic Englishes, for example General American, or some regional varieties of British English (e.g. speakers from Scotland or the south west), there will be an /r/ at the end of *career*, but not *Korea*.

In addition, in some varieties of English there is likely to be a full /ɒ/ sound (like the vowel in *hot*) in the first syllable of *Korea*, whilst there will still be a schwa, /ə/, in the first  of *career*. This is likely to be true of speakers from Yorkshire, who are likely to pronounce *Korea* as /kɒ'rɪə/.  These speakers also have a full /ɒ/ in word beginning with unstressed *con-* such as *concern*: /kɒn'sɜ:n/.

In short, for many non-rhotic speakers *career* and *Korea* are homophones, they are pronounced the same. But for rhotic speakers and some non-rhotic speakers the pronunciations might be noticeably different.  For these speakers *career* and *Korea* will be minimal pairs, where some feature of the pronunciation is sufficient for other speakers to be able to tell the two words apart.

Comment: Even in RP, I would at least optionally pronounce them differently: in careful speech, I would pronounce _career_ as [kə.ˈɹʷɪ͡ə] (disyllabic, second syllable being a diphthong with very little change in vowel quality), and _Korea_ as [kə.ˈɹʷiː.ə] (trisyllabic, the second syllable being a long, tense /iː/, the third being a single schwa /ə/). In rapid speech, I’d probably pronounce them both as monosyllables: [kɹʷɪː] (or perhaps [kɹʷɪːə̯] with a slight schwa offglide).

Comment: In ma neck of the woods, them two wordies are not at all the same sounding: *"He got himself a career in Korea now"* and *"In Korea there he got himself a career which pays good"*. This be surprising to me that so many native English speakers say them two wordies the same. Guess ah learn something new every day of me life, sometimes, maybe. Or is it, you BrE speakers speak that there dang east-pondian type of English, yup, that be it, I'd reckon.